# Word for very-fine, see through

Tags: single-word-requests

Uh,
I know there is a word starting with d. it sounds kinda like diophanus or something similar. It referes to very fine clothing, nearly see through clothing. I really don't know the word. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close--if you google the word that you think it is with a short description ("very fine clothing") the right word comes up.

Comment: @simchona i did try googling it. thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Diaphanous**, from Greek *diaphanês* "transparent, translucent", from *dia* "through" and *phainô* "to shine, appear".

Comment: @OckhamsRazor: No prob. I like your name.

Answer (score 1):

A synonym is **sheer**(^2), adj. [< ON. *skaerr*, bright] 1. very thin; transparent: said of textiles
(Webster's New World Dictionary, Warner Books Paperback Edition, c. 1984),
in case you need variety from lovely "diaphanous."