# What is a single word to describe 'Extremely Delicate'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want a suitable single word to use in the below sentence. I've included a few phrases which try and express the intent I wish to convey.

> As the twilight passes in front of me, casting its saffron glow through a gap in the door, I hear your mellifluous footsteps in the ***(gossamer thin) (extremely delicate)*** hallways of my self.

Comment: Mellifluous footsteps? Hallways of my self? You’re winding us up!

Comment: [word for very fine, see-through?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42060/word-for-very-fine-see-through/331689#331689) will overlap.

Comment: *Gossamery* is one word.

Comment: Have you considered whether your metaphor can possibly work with the adjective you request? How can a hallway be delicate, never mind extremely so? Perhaps if the floor boards are rotten, or the site is undermined by subsidence, but “the rotting hallway of my self” conveys a different idea to that I think you intend. Presumably it is your “self” that is delicate, in which case that is where the adjective should come. I would rewrite the whole thing; something like “tread softly, for you tread on my dreams”. Unless it’s been said before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word that implies fragility while being more poetic, and which rhymes with *mellifluous*, is [**diaphanous**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diaphanous):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : characterized by such fineness of texture as to permit seeing through
>     // *diaphanous* fabrics
>     // a *diaphanous* curtain
> **2** : characterized by extreme delicacy of form : ETHEREAL
>     // painted *diaphanous* landscapes
> **3** : INSUBSTANTIAL, VAGUE
>     // had only a *diaphanous* hope of success

Using it in the passage from the question:

> I hear your *mellifluous* footsteps in the ***diaphanous*** hallways of my self.

Answer (score 3):

*Ethereal* would be a good choice.

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=ethereal)

> adj.
>
> 1. Extremely light or delicate: "*An ant lion ... is lovely, long-bodied like a damselfly, with a pair of ethereal wings*"
>    (Jennifer Ackerman).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But I feel, Ethereal seems disconnected from the intended meaning of the phrase. I want something which has closer connotation to 'fragile'. Such as: 'my extremely fragile heart cannot take the excitation brought by the sensations of your love'.

Comment: @VigneswaraPrabhu, *Ethereal* perfectly fits the example sentence you've provided. Plus, you've said 'delicate' in the OP, not 'fragile'.